# MySQL: update single table one column data to another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table called `Cars`. The `Cars` table has three columns: `id int auto increment`, `foo varchar(255)`, `bar varchar(255)`.

I want to simply update all rows in the Cars table into the `bar` column with the same value from `foo` if `foo` is not null. So both foo and bar will have the same value after the update wherever foo is not null.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
update cars set
bar = foo
where foo is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE cars SET bar = foo WHERE foo IS NOT null
```

Answer (score 0):

The update query would be:

```
 UPDATE Cars set bar = foo where foo is not null
```